# HTTP Request to nasdaq RSS feed Works in Browser But Hangs with Code (C#, Node.js/Axios), Even with Identical Headers

Tags: c#, node.js, axios, rss, httpclient

I'm encountering a peculiar issue when trying to make an HTTP GET request to the URL 'https://www.nasdaq.com/feed/rssoutbound?category=FinTech'. When I manually enter this URL in my web browser, the feed loads without any issues. However, when I attempt to make the same request programmatically using code (I've tried C# with `HttpClient` and Node.js with Axios), the request hangs indefinitely and eventually times out.

Here's my C# code:

```cs
public async Task Execute()
{
    using HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
    try
    {
        // Specify the URL you want to request
        string url = "https://www.nasdaq.com/feed/rssoutbound?category=FinTech";

        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("*/*"));
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.AcceptLanguage.Add(new StringWithQualityHeaderValue("en-US"));
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.AcceptLanguage.Add(new StringWithQualityHeaderValue("en", 0.9));
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("sec-ch-ua", "\"Chromium\";v=\"116\", \"Not)A;Brand\";v=\"24\", \"Microsoft Edge\";v=\"116\"");
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("sec-ch-ua-mobile", "?0");
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("sec-ch-ua-platform", "\"Windows\"");
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("sec-fetch-dest", "empty");
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("sec-fetch-mode", "cors");
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("sec-fetch-site", "same-origin");

        // Add the User-Agent header
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/116.0.0.0 Safari/537.36");


        // Send a GET request and wait for the response
        HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync(url);

        // Check if the request was successful
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            // Read the content of the response as a string
            string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            // Print the content to the console
            Console.WriteLine(content);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"HTTP request failed with status code: {response.StatusCode}");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
        throw;
    }
}
```

I've also tried making the same request with Node.js and Axios, and the result is the same:

```js
// Node.js code using Axios
const axios = require('axios');

async function fetchData() {
    try {
        const response = await axios.get('https://www.nasdaq.com/feed/rssoutbound?category=FinTech', {
            headers: {
                Accept: '*/*',
                'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9,tr;q=0.8',
                'sec-ch-ua': '"Chromium";v="116", "Not)A;Brand";v="24", "Microsoft Edge";v="116"',
                'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
                'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"',
                'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
                'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
                'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
                'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/116.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
            }
        });
        // ... (handling the response)
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('An error occurred:', error.message);
    }
}

fetchData();
```

Strangely, when I attempt to retrieve feeds from other RSS sources, everything works fine. The issue seems to be specific to the Nasdaq feed. I've even tried using Puppeteer to fetch the content, and it also hangs indefinitely.

I used Edge (browser) tool to send request by clearing all editable headers and without cookie, and it still works. So I doubt it is a cookie problem.

[image]

And following PowerShell works as well;

```
$session = New-Object Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WebRequestSession
$session.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/116.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/116.0.1938.81"
Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing -Uri "https://www.nasdaq.com/feed/rssoutbound?category=FinTech" `
-WebSession $session `
-Headers @{
"authority"="www.nasdaq.com"
  "method"="GET"
  "path"="/feed/rssoutbound?category=FinTech"
  "scheme"="https"
  "accept"="*/*"
  "accept-encoding"="gzip, deflate, br"
  "accept-language"="en-US,en;q=0.9,tr;q=0.8"
  "sec-ch-ua"="`"Chromium`";v=`"116`", `"Not)A;Brand`";v=`"24`", `"Microsoft Edge`";v=`"116`""
  "sec-ch-ua-mobile"="?0"
  "sec-ch-ua-platform"="`"Windows`""
  "sec-fetch-dest"="empty"
  "sec-fetch-mode"="cors"
  "sec-fetch-site"="same-origin"
}
```

[image]

What could be causing this problem with the Nasdaq feed specifically? Is there something unique about their server configuration or the way they handle requests that might be causing this behavior? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Also look if it's a [cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31348390/why-does-my-webclient-return-a-404-error-most-of-the-time-but-not-always/31349305) problem.

Comment: @gunr2171 thanks for pointing that out. I resend the request from Edge browser by clearing all cookies and it still works well. I am getting 200. I am not sure how it sends request differently than HttpClients.

Comment: In your browser, view the HTTP request in the Dev Tools > network tab. Export the HTTP call to CURL/Powershell, and run it in your terminal. Does it look different or does it not work?

Comment: Yeah, PowerShell and curl works! But not fetch/axios/dotnet Http Libraries..

Answer (score 0):

Apparently problem was Gzip handling. Following code works:

```
 public async Task GetRssFeed(string url)
 {
     using HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
     try
     {
         HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, url);
         request.Headers.Add("authority", "www.nasdaq.com");
         request.Headers.Add("accept", "*/*");
         request.Headers.Add("accept-encoding", "gzip, deflate, br");
         request.Headers.Add("accept-language", "en-US,en;q=0.9,tr;q=0.8");
         request.Headers.Add("sec-ch-ua", "\"Chromium\";v=\"116\", \"Not)A;Brand\";v=\"24\", \"Microsoft Edge\";v=\"116\"");
         request.Headers.Add("sec-ch-ua-mobile", "?0");
         request.Headers.Add("sec-ch-ua-platform", "\"Windows\"");
         request.Headers.Add("sec-fetch-dest", "empty");
         request.Headers.Add("sec-fetch-mode", "cors");
         request.Headers.Add("sec-fetch-site", "same-origin");
         request.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/116.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/116.0.1938.81");

         HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
         response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
         if (response.Content.Headers.ContentEncoding.Contains("gzip"))
         {
             await using var responseStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
             await using var decompressedStream = new GZipStream(responseStream, CompressionMode.Decompress);
             using var streamReader = new StreamReader(decompressedStream);
             string decompressedContent = await streamReader.ReadToEndAsync();
             Console.WriteLine(decompressedContent);
         }
     }
     catch (Exception e)
     {
         Console.WriteLine(e);
         throw;
     }
 }
```