# Cookies HTML Agility Pack?

Tags: c#, cookies, html-agility-pack

This is a general question regarding web scraping.

When I web scrape certain sites. I receive a messages like this:

**Your browser must have browser cookies turned on**

I've been searching around for a solution and i'm guessing its something to do with storing cookies? I'm new to this so any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var getHtmlWeb = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb();
getHtmlWeb.UseCookies = true;
```

just add **getHtmlWeb.UseCookies = true;**

Comment: use the PostResponse method to respond to this event

Answer (score -2):

You need to enable cookies in the browser you are using . The following wiki will guide you depending on which browser you are using.

http://www.wikihow.com/Enable-Cookies-in-Your-Internet-Web-Browser

Comment: I have cookies enabled though. Does HTML agility pack use Internet Explorer by default? or do I need to specify what browser to use in my C# code?

Comment: My apologies is looks like your issue is related to HTML agility pack which I am unfamiar with. Check out this link on stack it may answer your question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15206644/how-to-pass-cookies-to-htmlagilitypack-or-webclient

Comment: html agility pack is not a browser, it mimics what a browser does, you need to turn on cookies as per the accepted answer